# React app runs locally, crashes when on Heroku error code=H10

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku

The app runs fine after an 'npm start' in windows, but when I pull from github into Heroku I just get an error.

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "tic-tac-toe",
  "version": "0.1.0",

  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.5.4",
    "react-dom": "^15.5.4"
  },
  "engines": {
      "node": "6.10.3",
      "npm":"3.10.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-scripts": "1.0.7"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

and the error log:

```
 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm bugs tic-tac-toe
 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm owner ls tic-tac-toe
 app[web.1]: npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
 app[web.1]: 
 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=react-tac-to.herokuapp.com request_id=c3cf2461-1989-4734-a7d5-157eb81c9643 fwd="24.29.73.46" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=react-tac-to.herokuapp.com request_id=05109629-cbb4-4927-9d13-8a3a37fedb93 fwd="24.29.73.46" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

The nature of the problem makes me think this is configuration based, and not in the main app.js code.
the main file is slightly long, so I'll link to it on Github if you want to see it:
https://github.com/owenpercoco/React-Tac-Toe

Comment: At a glance, can you confirm that `react-scripts` was installed properly? I believe that heroku ignores `devDependencies` modules by default. Moving it to the `dependencies` list might be able to solve this.

Comment: Thanks @hainq this solved my problem..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Heroku doesnt install devdependencies by default:. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support. Either set your react-scripts module to always install or turn off production mode on Heroku.

Comment: I'm having the same issue but I didn't get your solution.Can you please elaborate it?

Comment: Vasu, I had the same issue with an essentially clean slate create-react-app. Here's what I had to change: add `"heroku-postbuild": "npm run build"` to my scripts, then I ran "yarn add serve --save" to add the 'serve' command to my dependencies, then I changed my 'start' script to: `"start": "serve -s build",` per Sufyan's answer below. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks MarkW. Might add that by "scripts" you're referring to a part of the `package.json` file.

Answer (score 26):

I had the same problem, but the solution above did not work for my react app in Heroku. 
I have updated the build pack to create-react-app, and it worked for me.

`heroku buildpacks:set mars/create-react-app`

Comment: Worked like a charm

Comment: This one should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 23):

Just `npm i serve` to install serve then or you could use yarn instead of npm

You can change your scripts in package.json file, it seemed to be caused by update by react.

```
"scripts": {
"dev": "react-scripts start",
"start": "serve -s build",
"build": "react-scripts build",
"heroku-postbuild": "npm run build"}
```

Hope it fixes your problem.

Answer (score 10):

1.) `npm install serve --save` or `yarn install serve --save` in your terminal

```
"scripts": {
"dev": "react-scripts start",
"start": "serve -s build",
"build": "react-scripts build",
"test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
"eject": "react-scripts eject",
"heroku-postbuild": "npm run build"
}
```

2.) copied the above code in place of previous code "scripts" in my package.json file

3.) `git commit -am "new update"`

4.) `git push heroku master`

- Note: the common problem is missing the first step.

Comment: wow! that finally solved my problem!
the only problem is that I have no idea why....

Comment: @Dardar, if the first step was your case, it is because of the requirement of Heroku to having the 'serve' on your dependencies, then it is going to be able to handle that.

Answer (score 8):

I face the same problem, it has worked for me.

add "serve" to application.

example:
`npm add serve or yarn add serve`

after change scripts in package.json

```
"scripts": {
  "dev": "react-scripts start",
  "start": "serve -s build",
  "build": "react-scripts build",
  "heroku-postbuild": "npm run build"
}
```