# Heroku Application Error after push to heroku with code=H10

Tags: reactjs, heroku

I have created a react application, i have pushed it to heroku. But after pushing to heroku application URL displays "Application Error", and in console it says,

> "GET /favicon.ico 503 (Service Unavailable)"

On log :

> at=error **code=H10** desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/"

I have tried :

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 8000;
```

and added this to package.json,

```
"engines": {
    "node": "8.10.0",
    "npm": "6.4.1"
  },
```

also tried :

```
- git push heroku master
- heroku run rake db:migrate
- heroku restart
```

Here is my heroku log:

> Listening at http://localhost:8000 2018-12-11T17:53:29.508101+00:00
>   heroku[web.1]: **Process exited with status 0**
>
> 2018-12-11T17:53:29.802150+00:00 heroku[web.1]: **State changed from
>   starting to crashed**
>
> 2018-12-11T17:53:30.384102+00:00 heroku[router]:
>    at=error **code=H10** desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/"

Any possibilities?

Thanks in Advance..!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React app runs locally, crashes when on Heroku error code=H10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44319832/react-app-runs-locally-crashes-when-on-heroku-error-code-h10)

Answer (score 0):

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

So are using react or rails with react on heroku?

If you are using rails, is it in api mode or regular? How is the react app suppose to be connected to rails?

If api mode mind posting up your package.json that is in the root of your rails folder and your package.json of your react project?

In api mode you need to make sure heroku knows that you want both a node buildpack and a ruby buildpack:

```
heroku buildpacks:add heroku/nodejs --index 1
heroku buildpacks:add heroku/ruby --index 2
```

From: https://blog.heroku.com/a-rock-solid-modern-web-stack
ctrl+f : Step 5: Deploy it to Heroku

But need some more information to help out better.