# Deploying react app to heroku giving H10 error code

Tags: reactjs, heroku, create-react-app

I've created a react app using `create-react-app`.It is working well in my local server.But when I tried to deploy it to heroku it is crashing.I don't know why it is crashing.

In `heroku logs --tail` its showing `error code=H10 desc=App crashed`.I searched about this issue and nothing helpful for me.

My question is similar to this question : [React app runs locally, crashes when on Heroku error code=H10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44319832/react-app-runs-locally-crashes-when-on-heroku-error-code-h10)

But I'm unable to understand the solution they given.

My `package.json` file is as follows:

```
{
  "name": "lets-chat",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.28",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.13.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^5.13.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.13.0",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.9",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "firebase": "^7.14.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

I don't know what's wrong in this file.Should I make any changes in this file to get my problem solved?

`heroku logs --tail` gave the report as follows:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Check out this link (in case none of the solutions from that other post helped your case): https://dev.to/webdevraj/deploy-a-react-app-on-heroku-the-right-way-5efo
Pay attention to #6 where they mention the buildpack.

Answer (score 1):

When using create-react-app and deploying to

1. dont delete the favicon.ico and manifest.json
2. also in package.json above scripts insert "engines": {
   "npm": "6.x",
   "node": "12.x"
   },

//NOTE CHECK YOUR NODE AND NPM VERSIONS BY TYPING npm -v and node -v for accurate versions//

3. In heroku after heroku create command, go to heroku and change buildback under settings to https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack

Dont add other scripts or change the start, build scripts!

This should clear all h10 errors when deploying to heroku, if they dont i suggest you create a new directory and copy your files there and start over, this link is a great guide to deploy

https://dev.to/smithmanny/deploy-your-react-app-to-heroku-2b6f

Answer (score 0):

I also had same issue. I could figure out it is something to do with react version.
I changed the version and it worked. Update your version in package.json and see if it works.

```
"react": "^16.12.0",
"react-dom": "^16.12.0",
"react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
"react-scripts": "3.2.0"
```